# Script only copying one file

Tags: bash, shell, cron, expect, scp

I am trying to scp to transfer all files in a directory to a different box - however I seem to only be receiving one file on the other machine. The script I am using is as follows;

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp -r /var/opt/backup/mariadb/ user@ip:address:of:box:/var/opt/backup/
#######################
expect {
  -re ".*es.*o.*" {
   exp_send "yes\r"
   exp_continue
  }
  -re ".*sword.*" {
    exp_send "password\r"
  }
}
expect eof

echo "copy completed"
echo "removing backup files now"
rm -rf /var/opt/backup/mariadb
echo "remove completed"
echo "finished!"
```

From what I have read the recursive command is as I have implemented it so I am not so sure as to why i might only be receiving one file.

Can anyone see any issues with my code.

More information added : I've found that the copy is actually getting stuck on the following line events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name.frm

Thanks

output of less command on redirected log

```
^MSwifteHots.frm                                  0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MSwifteHots.frm                                100% 8600     8.4KB/s   00:00    
^MChatSessions.frm                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MChatSessions.frm                              100% 8626     8.4KB/s   00:00    
^MMessages.frm                                    0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MMessages.frm                                  100% 8640     8.4KB/s   00:00    
^MApnsDevices.frm                                 0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MApnsDevices.frm                               100% 8670     8.5KB/s   00:00    
^MAvailableHots.frm                               0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MAvailableHots.frm                             100% 8604     8.4KB/s   00:00    
^Mdb.opt                                          0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mdb.opt                                        100%   65     0.1KB/s   00:00    
^MShortlist.frm                                   0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MShortlist.frm                                 100% 8598     8.4KB/s   00:00    
^MProfileImages.frm                               0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MProfileImages.frm                             100% 8896     8.7KB/s   00:00    
^MPendingProfile.frm                              0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MPendingProfile.frm                            100% 8674     8.5KB/s   00:00    
^MUserAccount.frm                                 0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^MUserAccount.frm                               100% 9111     8.9KB/s   00:00    
^Mibdata1                                         0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mibdata1                                        32% 3280KB   3.2MB/s   00:02 ETA^Mibdata1                                        45% 4688KB   3.0MB/s   00:01 ETA^Mibdata1                                        58% 5968KB   2.8MB/s   00:01 ETA^Mibdata1                                        72% 7376KB   2.7MB/s   00:01 ETA^Mibdata1                                        84% 8656KB   2.6MB/s   00:00 ETA^Mibdata1                                        98%   10MB   2.4MB/s   00:00 ETA^Mibdata1                                       100%   10MB   1.7MB/s   00:06    
^Mxtrabackup_logfile                              0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mxtrabackup_logfile                            100% 2048KB   2.0MB/s   00:00    
^Mevents_waits_history.frm                        0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mevents_waits_history.frm                      100% 9220     9.0KB/s   00:00    
/var/tmp/cron.log (END)
```

Comment: I believe expect has a built-in timeout for how long a process will be waited on before being killed. If you `set timeout -1` in your expect script before you start does that fix things?

Comment: I am not familiar with expect, but I think there is a confusion. If call expect directly, it means you shebang should be "/bin/sh" and not "/usr/bin/expect". By the way, I think configuring key pair is more secure than hardcode its password (you can controle ;ore precisely the permissions on the secret)

Comment: When you say "copy only one file", does it mean your scp command finish with success ($? is equal to 0) and the script continue? Or does it mean the scp command is stuck? Something else?

Comment: i have added the output of less on the log file i redirect too

Comment: using the same user your script is run as, try to do the scp on the command line, and see if it asks for something. I see lots of "0%" "0.0KB/s", maybe scp doesn't work at all with what you use it with.

Comment: if i run the .sh file it works perfectly? only using cron does the above happen

Answer (score 0):

I would just use rsync instead of scp.

```
rsync -aP ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

here, the "-a" stands for "archive" and syncs recursively and preserves symbolic links, special and device files, modification times, group, owner, and permissions.
The "-P" shows you progress.

Note that there is no trailing slash from your source directory (a slash is used when doing local to local with rsync).